# The meeting this week vs. the meeting "on" this week

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I've always been confused about how to correctly use prepositions before time. In this case, my intuition tells me that I have to use *some* proposition before *this week*, but the search result is suggesting that I shouldn't use any of them. If a preposition is not required, what is the underlying grammar under "the meeting this week"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These websites might help you: https://textranch.com/25624/in-this-week/or/on-this-week/

> It is much more common to say "during this week," or simply, "**this week.**"

https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/prepositions-at-in-on-time.htm

> When we say last, next, every, **this** we do not also use at, in, on.

> We'll call you **this evening**. (not in this evening)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the articles! I wonder which grammar makes _not_ using any prepositions before _last, next, this, every_ correct.

Comment: I can't find very much on the internet to back me up here as for why, but I can just tell you that "this weekend" *is* more correct.  I've got more links to forums that answer the same question, and all simply say it is more correct.  One notes that "on this weekend" is a bit archaic.
https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/15235675
https://www.italki.com/post/question-148676
Sorry I can't help more here.

Comment: The links you provided me here helped me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: That's great to hear!  Glad to help. :)